# Surface tension between normal and superconductor phases

Tags: superconductivity, vortex

I am studying the phenomenological description of superconductors based on Tinkham's Introduction to Superconductivity. In Chapter 2.3.2. it discusses the difference between Type-1 and Type-2 superconductors based on the sign of the surface tension (denoted by $\gamma$) between the normal and the superconductor phases.

[image: Setup considered.]

The statement is that the above setup is stable if the surface tension between the NS phases is positive and that corresponds to a Type-1 superconductor, while negative surface tension corresponds to a Type-2 superconductor.

Isn't this statement contradictory? We have Abrikosov lattice in Type-2 SCs and that corresponds to a stable system of normal and super phases, just like on the figure. Meanwhile, negative surface tension means that the system reaches its energy minimum by expanding the NS surface meaning that the whole sample will be in normal phase.

What is the point I am missing regarding the argument of Tinkham?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a volume of fluid had negative surface tension, it would break up into lots of tiny spherical droplets because   small spheres have a larger surface to volume ratio that larger spheres. Similarly a tube of flux passing through a normal region in a  type II (negative surface energy) superconductor will   break up into the largest possible number of cylindrical flux tubes, each of these being an Abrikosov  vortex line with a single flux unit.  A large number of  small  flux tube cylinders  has  a much larger S/N surface area  than a single fat flux  tube that is  carrying the same  total flux.

If the whole material became normal there would be no S/N interface and  no  benefit at all from the negative energy of the interface.

Comment: Based on this I would say that negative surface tension does lead to a stable N/S state like on the figure. But the book claims that it is not possible.

Comment: It actually says:"If the surface energy were negative, we could not have a stable equilibrium of macroscopic volumes of the two phases. Instead, the interfaces would proliferate to gain negativesurface energy. This is essentially what we shall find happens in type II superconductors."

Comment: Okay I see the point. Thanks for the clarification.